# a regex expression to extract 1st group + 2nd group or 1st group only if no 2nd group (including variations)

Tags: regex

The best way to explain it is to show exactly what I'm looking to achieve:

- case 1: `"search for fenway park in boston"`
  Extract: group 1 -->
  `"fenway park"`, group 2 --> `"boston"`
- case 2:`"search for fenway park"`
  Extract: group 1 --> `"fenway
  park"`

**Note that in both cases, I want to be able to cater for variations of `"search"` (`"look for"`, `"find"`, etc...) and of `"in"` (`"at"`, `"around"`, etc...).**

I've tried many different variations but either end up with extracting `"fenway park in boston"` in group 1 and nothing in group 2 or if I get case 1 right, case 2 won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you

```
^(?:search for|look for|find)\s*(.*?)(?:\s*(?:in|around|at)\s*(.*))?$
```

You can add more clauses like `look for/in/at` by adding moer **or** clauses to the non-capturing groups.

**Explanation:**

```
@"
^                   # Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
(?:                 # Match the regular expression below
                       # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      search\ for         # Match the characters “search for” literally
   |                   # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      look\ for           # Match the characters “look for” literally
   |                   # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      find                # Match the characters “find” literally
)
\s                  # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                   # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *?                  # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
(?:                 # Match the regular expression below
   \s                  # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
      *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (?:                 # Match the regular expression below
                          # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         in                  # Match the characters “in” literally
      |                   # Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         around              # Match the characters “around” literally
      |                   # Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         at                  # Match the characters “at” literally
   )
   \s                  # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
      *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (                   # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
      .                   # Match any single character that is not a line break character
         *                   # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
)?                  # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$                   # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
"
```

Comment: Thanks for your very well documented answer. Unfortunately I'm getting the same result: it works for "search for fenway park in boston" and correctly extracts each group separately but doesn't match anything in "search for fenway park" because the "in|around|at" group is not optional. If I make it optional then everything is matched in one group (not what I want).

Comment: @BlazingFrog Updated the regex. Check it now.

Comment: Awesome! I'm now understanding what I think was doing wrong: I was making both group ("on|in" and "boston") optional but *separately*. You enclosed both within one group and made that one group optional and looks like it did the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: If I could upvote this twice, I would! Awesome work. My only change would be to change both \s* into \s+ - otherwise you could match "no whitespace", and find that "search forfenway parkin boston" matches.

Comment: @dty thanks for the comments. i was thinking about `\s+` you mentioned  and was wondering that `\s*` could be a feature and not a bug as it takes care of the spelling mistakes in a way ;)

Comment: Haha nice. I actually tried to answer this question for about 10 minutes then gave up :-).